# Why is RegExp.escape not working in my Ruby expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, whitespace

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have some strings that contain characters that have special meaning in regular expression.  So to eliminate any possibility of those characters being interpreted as regexp characters, I use the "Regexp.escape" to attempt to escape them.  However, I still seem unable to make teh below regular expression work ...

```
2.4.0 :005 >   tokens = ["a", "b?", "c"]
 => ["a", "b?", "c"] 
2.4.0 :006 > line = "1\ta\tb?\tc\t3"
 => "1\ta\tb?\tc\t3" 
2.4.0 :009 > /#{Regexp.escape(tokens.join(" ")).gsub(" ", "\\s+")}/.match(line)
 => nil
```

How can I properly escape the characters before substituting the space with a "\s+" expression, whcih I do want interpreted as a regexp character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `Regexp.escape(tokens.join(" ")).gsub(" ", "\\s+")` is executed, `tokens.join(" ")`  yields `a b? c`, then the string is escaped -> `a\ b\?\ c`, and then the `gsub` is executed resulting in `a\\s+b\?\\s+c`. Now, `line` is `1   a   b?  c   3`. So, all `\\` are now matching a literal backslash, they no longer form an special regex metacharacter matching whitespace.

You need to escape the tokens, and join with `\s+`, or join with space and later replace the space with `\s+`:

```
/#{tokens.map { |n| Regexp.escape(n) }.join("\\s+")}/.match(line)
```

OR

```
/#{tokens.map { |n| Regexp.escape(n) }.join(" ").gsub(" ", "\\s+")}/.match(line)
```